# Reduce .net core 2.0 memory usage on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, .net

can anyone tell me to reduce .net core 2.0 memory usage on Ubuntu 16.04 to around 10 mb or low. Currently its using 70-80 mb of memory. thats good for dynamic website but high for a static one.

I want something like php fpm pool ondemand thread attribute which is good for demo wesbites to show to client. It uses memory only when executed and then releases the memory back to system.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an expected behavior on asp.net core chooses to use Server GC by default. You can turn off this feature to reduce the resource utilization. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134508/what-is-server-garbage-collection-in-asp-net-core) for more information regarding this.

Comment: will this work in ubuntu since i dont think csproj file is included when i publish the website